# Find the "best" combination of three columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, max, min

I have a dataframe with three columns e.g.

```
a <- c(1,214,124,124,64,43)
b <- c(0.1,0.9,0.8,0.25,0.3,0.11)
c <- c(1000,12311,2221,5676,3234,7346)
myframe <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Now I want to find the best combination of a, b and c. The best combination would be where a is the highest, b the lowest and c the highest. If there are more than one combination where b and c are the lowest respective highest, a should be the deciding factor.

How can this be achived?

Comment: Try reading `?order`

Comment: what is the desired result with the data you provided?

Comment: why you name a vector with "c"? Please never use "c" as a new vector name as its an inbuilt object in R , "c" is a generic function which combines its arguments, Read ?c

Comment: I am sorry, but obviously I did not explain what I want correctly. There should always be a combination returned in the case of my example row 2 (214,0.9,12311) is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated, based on your edit. If you want to order the rows of dataframe by highest a, lowest b, lowest c (applying the conditions in that order), then use:

```
with(myframe, order(-a, b, c))
```

Output (row order):

```
[1] 2 4 3 5 6 1
```

If you want just the 'best' single row (i.e. the first result from the ordering above):

```
myframe[with(myframe, order(-a, b, c))[1],]
```

Output:

```
    a    b     c
2 214 0.90 12311
```

Comment: I do not want to re-order the rows of the dataframe. I just want the row to be returned.

Comment: @user3347232  As GSee mentioned, why don't you show the expected output?

Comment: Ok. Updated based on your edit.

Answer (score 0):

To find "the best combination where a is the highest, b the lowest and c the highest":

```
> apply(myframe, 1, function(x) ifelse(x[1]==max(myframe$a) && x[2]==min(myframe$b) && x[3]==max(myframe$c), x,""  ))
[1] "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

There seems to be no such combination in current data frame.

Comment: I am sorry, but obviously I did not explain what I want correctly. There should always be a combination returned in the case of my example row 2 (214,0.9,12311) is the correct answer.

Comment: 0.9 is not minimum of b; 0.1 (first row is minimum)!

Comment: Yes! But a trumps b...and b trums c.